# Do the Rabbis determine the laws of nature

Tags: rabbis, nature

A Rabbi has the power of Torah to affect the physical existence. The Gemora Yerushalmi brings a case were a girl lost her virginity after she turned three. Later, the Beis Din determined that that year should be a leap year and retroactively she was not yet three years old at the time. This Halachic ruling influences her physical body that her virginity will grow back. This unique power to create a "Psak Din" that establishes fact is given only to Rabbonim.

Are there other cases where we see this principle

Comment: Please give a precise reference to the case you cite.

Comment: Did her virginity grow back or did they declare her a virgin? It is true that a psak din creates a halachic reality but, at least today, not a physical reality. Unfortunately our Rabbis are not like their Rabbis ...

Comment: We have examples where nevi'im overturned the laws of nature for a while (Koheles Rabbah 3:14 gives a bunch of examples). Would those be an answer, or are you looking specifically for cases where they issued a psak din?

Comment: I am looking for cases where based on a psak din, the laws of nature changed

Answer (score -3):

God is perfect — the laws of nature were established by God; therefore, the laws of nature are perfect. We know that whatever is of God’s doing is unalterable by man beyond the laws of nature which the Creator has ordained. We cannot make a tree grow with the root in the air and the fruit in the ground; and we cannot make rays of light shine forth rays of darkness.

Only God is in control of the laws of nature. Rabbis are men with no control over nature.

Comment: not true 
: "Tsadik Gozèr Véhakadoch Baroukh Hou Mékayem"
And the reverse holds true
HM gozer and tsadik can break the gzeiros

Comment: @L770 This is nonsense and impossible. Where they are able to make a tree grow with the root in the air and the fruit in the ground? Did they make rays of light shine forth rays of darkness?

Comment: @L770 Can you do it?

Comment: I am not a tzadik obviously I cannot do that, so you do not believe in this sentence which is brought back time and time again in the gemara

Comment: @L770 Can any tzadik (a human) alter the natural laws? Everybody is a law-abiding citizen to the laws of physics. There's not a single case that we know of of the laws of physics ever being violated by anything, not even an inanimate object. Not a rock. Not a sage. Not a tzadik, and not even you. Everybody is a law-abiding citizen to the laws of physics. You're never going to see gravity not work. Period.

Comment: ok so can you explain this sentence of the talmud ??

Comment: @L770 Which sentence are you referring to? Can you post it here, please?